# Delete confirmation alert before deleting from Table view Datasource

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, datasource

I am trying to show an alert before you delete a row from the UITable view.

But how can i do this without passing my view controller interface to the Datasource.

```
    class BaseTableDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

       func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
           if editingStyle == .Delete {

            //1. Show alert and delete the block

            ??? But how can you show the alert with out View controller reference??
            //viewcontroller.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually I prefeer to create a sharedInstance notification manager to handle my alerts but on-the-fly you can try this method:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.delegate = self
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
window.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true,completion: nil)
```

UPDATE:

Based from your code you can also do:

```
if let tableViewController = tableView.delegate {
       tableViewController.presentViewController(alert, animated: true,completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: reason behind posting the question is to find out the elegant way of doing it. I will see if anyone else comes up with better answer.

Comment: I've update my code, try this solution..maybe can be better than passing throught window :)

Answer (score -1):

There are few ways to do this.

1) Ugly one: Send NSNotification from your BaseTableDataSource and catch it at ViewController side. As object for NSNotification - you can pass an "AlertActionViewModel" or something that will configure UIAlertActionController

2) You can create a callback through delegate or closure. But at the end you will loose whole idea of BaseTableDataSource, so it won't be only data source anymore.

Hope this will help.

Comment: 1. Don't want to use the ugly one, i would rather not use data source at all.
2. yeah the whole point why you created data source is lost.

Comment: -1 for `NSNotification` when they are not necessary. Check this link out: https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/07/16/uitableview-swipe-to-delete-workflow-in-swift/